# How to downgrade to Angular 7 from Angular 8 or 9

Tags: angular, npm

So I was trying to upgrade our entire web-application earlier from Angular 6 to 7. And I was able to do that since the script I run earlier installed the most latest version available of Angular which is Angular 8 (should have been 7 though as I thought) release 2 days ago. But it turns out there are build issues in the node modules when I did the upgrade to Angular 8. So instead, I want to downgrade my project from Angular 8 to Angular 7. How do I do that?. TIA.

PS:
I did not expect that there is Angular 8 alright, so I thought it would install Angular 7 as the latest version.

Comment: Are you not using git or any other versioning system?

Comment: I do, but I came from Angular 6 to Angular 8 immediately. Non of my existing package used Angular 7.

Comment: Then you should upgrade from angular 6 to angular 7 instead. Just changing the version numbers in the package.json should do the trick.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to angular, is it okay to just copy paste the dependecies I could find in the web, cuz I was seeing Angular 7 package.json files like in github. Is that fine?. It's just that I'm scared of breaking the application. When mine was still at angular 6, it got automatically upgraded or changed from Angular 6 version numbers to angular 8 versions.

Comment: Rollback to an older version of git, and start over by migrating to Angular 7 first. Open a new question if you have build errors, and show the error and explain why you can't fix it.

Comment: i did just earlier, apparently I'm encountering all the same build errors from Angular 6, 7 and 8.I thought the error I was encountering was due to angular 8. Turns out its problematic dependencies in my local machine it seems or remote dependencies?. hmm. Anyhow, thx. I am curious as to how I would do downgrade anyway from Angular 8 to 7 if ever I did create a project in angular 8 first.

Comment: The Angular team has provided upgrade migration scripts as part of the Angular CLI. Things like updating RxJS require code changes, and routes in Angular 8 require code changes. To downgrade, one would have to reverse those changes *manually*. Thus, you have to read the migration guides and reverse those changes yourself. I have never heard of anyone attempting this, but I'm sure it happens. It's not something I would ever want to do myself. If you enter 7 to 6 in the guide, then it complains that downgrading is not supported. https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Ah okay, so that's why when I accidentally migrated from 6 to 8, some of the version got changed automatically, and some others not so, but then I was able to fix manually immediately. All the other versions got migrated automatically to its proper angular 8 equivalent which is great and less of a hassle for me. I thought it would just do the same when done with a downgrade. Great. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try like this :

```
ng --version
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2.12
ng --version
```

**Update**

The version 7.2.12 is given the following error :

> npm ERR! code ETARGET
>   npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@7.2.12
>   npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
>   npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

use this instead :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2
```

Comment: Hi, where do I find the complete list of possible angular versions I could install?. with the npm install?.

Comment: might I ask, how do I make my project compile in this and automatically change the package.json versions to the proper angular 7 versions?. as of the moment I deleted the entire node_modules directory.

Comment: You should do it manually run `ng build` first to compile your code get ` ./dist` directory with current version then upgrade/downgrade you package.json for the wanted version

Comment: cuz globally I have 7.1.1, but since my packages are automatically ported to 8.0 version in the package.json file when I upgraded from angular 6. How do I do it automatically when downgrading from Angular 8 to angular 7?

Comment: I just forgot where and how my angular 6 project got ported automatically that easily before as I already have a global angular cli version of 8.0 and also my application and package.json file got automatically upgraded to the proper versions in the package.json to work with angular 8 though.

Comment: The best choice here, in my opinion, start a new project with version 7.1.1 (ng new ....) after this copy you src from the old directory to the new one and `ng server` if it compiles correctly it done if not try to fix broken parts

Comment: npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@7.2.12

Comment: @iamjoshua visit https://update.angular.io/ for a cool guide on how to update each version, as well as a list of all possible versions. You can also see the versions on NPM's site. Just google the package name.

Comment: I try it, but it sill version 8.0.1 when check ng --version.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the version while install,

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.x.x
```

if you dont specify it will install latest version , incase specified will install given version.

here is the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#install-specific-version-example-611), list of angular version and its command..

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but personally I would try the accepted answer, but also do a complete npm uninstall of *all* packages before installing the v7.2.12 CLI, and do a full npm install after installing the v7.2.12 CLI

Answer (score 0):

First Uninstall the angular

> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

> npm cache clean --force

Then check version

```
ng -v
```

Then install new version  (i mense install)

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: you check the version with `ng --version` or `ng version` not ng -v